# Button positioning issue in a form

Tags: html, css

If you look at my website http://goo.gl/GchAbB you'll notice that the "OK" green button is not placed to the left of the input field in the popup newsletter box as I would like it to be (see also the picture below). What I don't understand is that elements are perfectly positioned  on a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Md7X8/)

So I guess there's other parts of my code conflicting with the newsletter form but can't figure out what and how to fix this.

Thanks fo your help

**Edit**: code updated based on John C findings

[image]

```
/******NEWSLETTER *****/

#newsletterpopup {
    display: none;
    width: 400px;
    padding:10px;
    line-height:14px;
}

#newsletterpopup h1{
    font-size: 16px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    font-weight:600;
        text-transform: uppercase;

}
#newsletterpopup p{
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight:300;
    padding-bottom: 20px;

}

.non-merci {
padding-top: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    bottom: 5px;
    right: 5px;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: white;
    padding: 8px 18px;
    margin: 18px 0 0 0px;
    text-decoration: none;
        background: rgba(71, 186, 255, 0.8);

    -webkit-transition: background 0.3s ease;
    -moz-transition: background 0.3s ease;
    -ms-transition: background 0.3s ease;
    -o-transition: background 0.3s ease;
    transition: background 0.3s ease;

       cursor: pointer;

}


.non-merci:hover {
    background: rgba(71, 186, 255, 1);
}

.newsletter-field {
  display: block;
  width: 240px;
  height: 30px;
  float:left;
  padding-right: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  border-top-width: 1px;
  border-right-width: 1px;
  border-bottom-width: 1px;
  border-left-width: 1px;
  border-top-color: #d9d9d9;
  border-right-color: #d9d9d9;
  border-bottom-color: #d9d9d9;
  border-left-color: #d9d9d9;
  border-top-style: dotted;
  border-right-style: dotted;
  border-bottom-style: dotted;
  border-left-style: dotted;
  background-color: #efefef;
  line-height: 1.38;
  color: #444444;

    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    animation-direction: alternate;
    -moz-animation-direction: alternate;
    -webkit-animation-direction: alternate;
    -o-animation-direction: alternate;

    }


.newsletter-button {
  display: block;
  width: 40px;
  height: 32px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  background-color: rgb(202, 224, 84);
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
}


/****** END NEWSLETTER *****/
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

quick glance shows that your `<form>` has a width of 60%. This pushes the box down. Additionally, your margin on your `.newsletter-button` isn't correct. (it inherits a right-margin that pushes it down)

[edit]
I recommend setting:

```
.newsletter-button { margin : 0; }
form.form-newsletter { width: 100%; }
```

Comment: Thanks. Indeed, this is because I have 2 forms, one who needs the 60%, but the newsletter don't. Should I name the newsletter form "form2" or something and set a width of 100%? Or keep "form" and add a class with "width "100%" for the newsletter? Many thanks

Comment: I've just tried to add a class, but now the OK button is placed behind the "x non merci" button and still below the input field not at the same level :-/

Answer (score 0):

In `.newsletter-button`, you have `margin-left: 10px;`.  If you change that to `0`, it will be left-aligned with the field.

Comment: Thanks. I have updated the code as per your suggestion (you can check the link) but that doesn't solve the issue. I put the margin-left 10px to have some room between the input field and the button

Comment: On styles.css, line 207, I still see the `10px`. When I change this via the dev tools, it left aligns.

Comment: `margin-right` on your `button` is also moving it, forcing it down below the natural flow of the input field.

Comment: Thanks. I've figured out the issue, "button" used for something else is creating the conflict